# Xamarin, Android: Hand a Context into a Service class, when constructors are forbidden...?

Tags: xamarin, gps

So I have a service in my app that is supposed to be handed over a Context from my MainActivity. But I cannot create a constructor in my service, Visual Studio tells me then, that a service always uses a default constructor.

The problem is this bit of code:

```
   var test = new MockTheLocation(this);
   test.getMockLocation2();
```

This bit WAS in my main activity. I could create an object of my class "MockTheLocation" and hand over a context (this). 
In MockTheLocation I had this constructor:

```
    public MockTheLocation(Context cxt)
    {
        this.ctxt = cxt;
    }
```

This was necessary to call the location manager.

I used to do it like that, and it definitely worked! But now I moved it all into a service class, that calls the "getMockLocation2()" method. 
So how do I move my context from the MainActivity, to the service to then hand it over finally into the MockTheLocation class? I know it's a bit weired, but I didnt find any other way to do it.

Short version: I cannot create a constructor in my service, but I need it to call my mocked location :)

How could i achieve that?

THANKS :)

Comment: You can get the Application level Android context via `Application.Content`

Comment: `Service` is a `Context` as it extends `ContextWrapper`. Otherwise you can get the application `Context` by using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext() (`ApplicationContext` in Xamarin.Android`)